# No test assemblies found on the test machine 'Aborted state' - VM Test Agent running Selenium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, task, azure-devops

Setup:

1. VS CI build configured (pass)
2. Deploy TestAgent on VM (pass)
3. AzureVM File Copy (pass)
4. Run Functional Tests - Selenium (broken)

Here are the logs/errors that I see when this build step executes:

- Preparing task execution handler.
- Executing the powershell script:
  d:\a_tasks\RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent_d353d6a2-e361-4a8f-8d8c-123bebb71028\1.0.52\RunDistributedTests.ps1
- DistributedTests: Environment WinRm Protocol HTTPS.
- DistributedTests: Task 'CheckTACompat' on machine
  'AzureVM.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com:5986' is being run
- DistributedTests: Task 'CheckTACompat' on machine
  'AzureVM.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com:5986' completed.
- DistributedTests: Creating run for selected test plan with following
  parameters
- DistributedTests: Test plan ID: 15
- DistributedTests: Test suite ID: 16,18
- DistributedTests: Test configuration ID: 3
- DistributedTests: Run title: Selenium Test Run
- DistributedTests: is automated: True
- DistributedTests: test settings id : 38
- DistributedTests: build location:
  C:\seleniumwd\seleniumtestproject\bin\debug\
- DistributedTests: build id: 70
- DistributedTests: test configuration mapping:
- DistributedTests: Test Run with Id 41 Queued
- DistributedTests: Please use this link to analyze the test run :
- <>
- DistributedTests: Test run '41' is in 'InProgress' state.
- DistributedTests: Total Tests : 2, Passed Tests : 0
- DistributedTests: Test run '41' is in 'Aborted' state.
- DistributedTests: Total Tests : 2, Passed Tests : 0
- DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run
  logs.
- DistributedTests: New test run created.
- Test Run queued for Project Collection Build Service (App
  Service).
- DistributedTests: Test execution started. Test run id : 41
- DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try
  again.
- DistributedTests: Error : One or more errors occurred.--->No test
  assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter
  criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria. Verify
  that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter
  criteria is correct.
- DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 41 System.Exception:
  The test run was aborted, failing the task. PowerShell script
  completed with 1 errors.

In my Azure File copy task I have this:
Source: $/baseproject/SeleniumTestProject1
Destination Folder: C:\seleniumwd\seleniumtestproject\

If I go to the Azure VM and look at that destination folder, I see the following files/folders inside

- bin
- obj
- Properties
- Packages
- 3 C# selenium tests (.cs)
- 1 test project (seleniumTestProject)

bin/debug/ on the test agent contains the test project dll (SeleniumTestProject.dll) and all the dlls and webdriver files.

obj/debug/ on the test agent contains the test project dll (SeleniumTestProject.dll) and some text and cache files

When I point the Run Functional Tests task at either of the above folders, I get the error mentioned earlier.

If I switch the test task to use Assemblies instead of test plan I am still not successful.

Any ideas how to properly point to the assemblies?

Comment: Could you provide the detail log here or share it on the OneDrive? What's the detail setting of Run functional test?

Comment: Details of "Run Functional Tests"
*Test Drop Location - Folder from Azure copy
*Test Selection - Test Plan
* Test Plan - 001 Test Plan
* Test Suite - 001 Test Plan, 001 Test Plan\74: As a user I want to
* Test Configuration - Windows 10
* Code Coverage - Enabled

Comment: https://1drv.ms/t/s!Arm4oAAbRKsLa9ywijID0-b2U-8

Comment: Which folder to we want to point the test task @?  Do we point it to the folder that contains the drivers and dlls, or the folder that contains the .cs files?

Comment: I don't have a lot of build minutes left this month so that is why I'm selective when I build while we troubleshoot.

Comment: The dll files can be in the child folder of specified folder in Run Functional Task. Are there automated test cases linked to the test method in SeleniumTestProject.dll? Regarding build minutes, you can setup a private build agent.

Comment: What's the detail error message in the test run?

Comment: There are automated tests associated to the selenium tests.  The detailed output is in the 3rd comment.  That is the link to OneDrive that you requested and the file is still available.

Comment: I did some troubleshooting this time along with a build attempt.  Before I did the build I noticed that the .cs for the selenium tests were not being copied to the destination folder in the 'Azure Copy' task.  2 of the 4 selenium.cs files were there so I manually copied over the other 2.

I ran the build and now the test task times out with the following logs.
2017-07-25T15:35:42.5463560Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 3, Passed Tests : 0
2017-07-25T15:35:52.6468503Z ##[error]The task has timed out.

I'll build again with a longer or infinite timeout for this task.

Comment: What's the detail errors in test run? (The URL is in the build log, such as https://citfstestproject.visualstudio.com/webproject/_TestManagement/Runs#_a=resultQuery&runId=57&queryPath=Recent+Run%2FRun+57)

Comment: I believe the issue has been resolved as I was able to get the tests to run.  The error "No test assemblies" is no longer being displayed.  I saw a new error about the task being labelled as "failed" because one or more tests failed - which is great!  I found the issue with the one test and resolved it.  The very next time I tried to deploy and run the build, I started receiving WinRM errors about SSL not listening.  Not sure how that changed, but I'm sure it's because of the updates to my Win 10 VM.

Comment: I am now fully resolved, and would like you or myself to provide an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says that there were some missing test assemblies found in the test drop location.  I will post bullet points of things that I troubleshooted and confirmed while working on this issue.

**ISSUES**

- MTM tests were linked to some selenium tests and some unit tests
- If there are test cases that are linked to unit tests or selenium
  tests that don't exist, you will get this error.  All tests that are
  part of the plan must have an associated test that is in the test
  drop location
- There are some issues with the Azure copy as some of the .cs files
  are not being included in the copy (part of the original problem)

**TIPS**

- While initially setting up this test task you might set the timeout
  to 0.  I've seen times where there are selenium tests still being run
  and the task times out
- Select a test plan that has a few manual tests and linked selenium tests while initially setting up this task.  This will ensure you get to see one complete
- 1 failed selenium test in the task will fail the task
- You don't need to set up the agent for "Interactive Mode"